# MaxWitdh of Path

Tags: wpf, xaml, path

I'm developing an app and I'm facing the same problem.
For some reason, **Path** does not stretch to the entire area of ​​the program window (I programmatically stretch the application window to two screens), but the Path seems to have its own limit **Width**. Here is the markup of the **Path** itself

```
    <Grid >
    <InkCanvas Name="inkCanvas" 
           Cursor="Cross" 
           UseCustomCursor="True" 
           EditingMode="{Binding EditingMode}">
        <InkCanvas.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding CloseAppCommand}" 
                    Key="Esc"/>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding DrawModeCommand}" 
                    Key="F1"/>
        </InkCanvas.InputBindings>

        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <if:MouseBehaviour MouseX="{Binding MouseX, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                           MouseY="{Binding MouseY, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <InkCanvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Screenshot.Source}"></ImageBrush>
        </InkCanvas.Background>

        <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Green" Opacity=".3">
            <Path.Data>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding BlackoutRect.Rect}" >
                        </RectangleGeometry>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding SelectionRect.Rect}" >
                        </RectangleGeometry>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </InkCanvas>
</Grid>
```

As a result, we see the following picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s0mP.jpg

For example, if we specify **Width="300px"** for the path

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Green" Opacity=".3" Width="300px"...
```

, then the width of the green area on the screen above will actually be **300px**, but if you specify for example **300000px**, the picture will be the same as on the screen above. That is, I concluded that the **Path** element has a maximum width (by the way, if you specify **MaxWitdh="30000px"**, then nothing will change anyway and it will be the same as in the screenshot above)

Hence the main question of this thread: How to change the maximum size of a Path element?

Comment: InkCanvas does not stretch or otherwise modify the size of its child elements.

Comment: @Clemens is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You may perhaps bind its Width and Height to the ActualWidth and ActualHeight of the InkCanvas, like `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=InkCanvas}}"`. You can also put it into a Grid that has its Width and Height bound that way, in case there are more child elements.

Comment: You would also have to set `Stretch="Uniform"` or `Stretch="Fill"` on the Path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An InkCanvas does not stretch its child elements.

You could add a Panel that performs the desired layout, and bind its Width and Height to the ActualWidth and ActualHeight of the parent InkCanvas:

```
<InkCanvas ...>
    ...
    <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=InkCanvas}}"
          Height="{Binding ActualHeight,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=InkCanvas}}">

        <Path Stretch="Uniform" ...>
            ...
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</InkCanvas>
```